# How do I make sure that reducer response action is done before navigating to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux-saga

I'm currently using Redux Saga with React Native and I have a question on how to properly handle the situation where the reducer action is not done firing a success or fail action before I navigate to another page. I need to wait until the success or fail action is fired before navigating to another page but it navigates anyway.

I set up my code so that it checks for loading or error state before navigation but navigation still happens anyway. I think it's because updateItems is async and the proceeding codes executes so quickly before the response comes back e.g. in the event that I do get an error, the page navigates away instead of waiting so that I can display the error on the page.

I think it might be related to something I need to add in my reducer but I'm not sure.

Here's the method that I click on that triggers the reducer call and the navigation is all is well.

```
updateItems = () => {
    const { code } = this.state;
    const { loading, error } = this.props;
    const id = this.props.navigation.state.params.id;

    this.props.updateItems({
      id: id,
      code: code,
    });

    if (!loading && !error) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("newPage");
    }
  };
```

Here's the reducer itself:

```
const UPDATE_ITEMS_REQUEST = "UPDATE_ITEMS_REQUEST";
const UPDATE_ITEMS_SUCCESS = "UPDATE_ITEMS_SUCCESS";
const UPDATE_ITEMS_FAILURE = "UPDATE_ITEMS_FAILURE";

export default (itemsReducer = (
  state = {
    data: {
      items: {},
    },
    error: null,
    loading: false,
  },
  { type, payload },
) => {
  switch (type) {
    case UPDATE_ITEMS_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { loading: true, error: null });
    case UPDATE_ITEMS_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { loading: false, error: payload });
    case UPDATE_ITEMS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: null,
        data: payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
});

export function updateItems(payload) {
  return { type: UPDATE_ITEMS_REQUEST, payload };
}

export function updateItemsFailure(payload) {
  return { type: UPDATE_ITEMS_FAILURE, payload };
}

export function updateItemsSuccess(payload) {
  return { type: UPDATE_ITEMS_SUCCESS, payload };
}


function* updateItemsSaga(payload) {
  const response = yield call(putItems, payload);
  if (response.ok) {
    yield put(updateItemsSuccess(payload));
  } else {
    yield put(
      updateItemsFailure("There has been an error"),
    );
  }
}

export function* watchUpdateItems() {
  yield takeLatest(UPDATE_ITEMS_REQUEST, updateItemsSaga);
}

// API
const putItems = async payload => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `${env.url}/updateItems`,
    {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: payload.payload.id,
        code: payload.payload.code,
      }),
    },
  );

  if (!res.ok)
    return {
      status: res.status,
      ok: false,
    };

  const response = await res.json();
  response.status = res.status;
  response.ok = res.ok;
  return response;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue is located in `updateItems`. It have an internal scope with two properties `{ loading, error }`. Since this is not a generator function, As soon as this function starts executing, an action `updateItems` is fired (which is fine), and right after that the navigation happens because the function checks `{ loading, error }` (which are `false` & `null` accordingly).

The solution can be using the navigation part inside `updateItemsSaga` like so:

```
function* updateItemsSaga(payload) {
  const response = yield call(putItems, payload);
  if (response.ok) {
    yield put(updateItemsSuccess(payload));
    this.props.navigation.navigate("newPage");
  } else {
    yield put(
      updateItemsFailure("There has been an error"),
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can extract the condition from `updateItems` and use it in your component itself:

```
const OldPage = ({ loading, error }) => {

    if (loading) {
        return <div>Loading... </div>
    } else if(error) {
        return <ErrorPage status="404">;
    } else {
        return <NewPage>;
    }

};
```

Both should stop the navigation from happening, until items have updated successfully. Hope it helps

Comment: But I only want to navigate to New Page on clicking on a button in my Old Page. That latter flow won't work and I don't want to display an error page but an error message that is displayed on the page itself.

Comment: Also how does my reducer /saga know about this.props.navigation if I use the first approach? @jank

Comment: @Euridice01 - I need more information about the navigation prop, if its an action, then you can dispatch it in the saga. if its a function coming from a module, then you can import and use it in the saga as well. let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can redirect user to new route inside redux action using react routers useHistory [more info on how to route](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/)
2. You can add a flag and set it to true in response